# Disable setTimeout function if screen width is greater then 1200px?

Tags: javascript

I have 16 dynamically created div with background images. I have a function where I add a style to each background image display none and block which I am looping over and over again.

This currently works if the screen width is less then 1200px and only on reload/init.

The biggest problem I am facing now When the screen width is greater than 1200px on init and I resize back to like 1000px the animation won't start.

What I am trying to accomplish is that when I resize down and over 1200px that the display block/none will work on window size: < 1200px and stop working if screen is > 1200px.

Working Demo: https://codepen.io/Merdzanovich/pen/abbvPGv

Can someone help?

Code:

```
(() => {
    const hero = document.getElementById('hero');

    if (!hero) {
        return;
    }

    const shuffle = array => {
        let currentIndex = array.length;
        let temporaryValue, randomIndex;

        while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
    };

    const images = Array.from(Array(16).keys(), n => n + 1);
    const shuffleArray = shuffle(images);
    let imgArr = [];
    let counter = 0;

    function roll() {
        imgArr.map(img => (img.style.display = 'none'));
        imgArr[counter].style.display = 'block';
        counter++;
        if (counter === imgArr.length - 1) {
            counter = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(() => roll(), 500);
    }

    const init = () => {
        shuffleArray.forEach(image => {
            let imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
            imageDiv.className = `bg-image bg-image-bg${image}`;
            hero.appendChild(imageDiv);
            imgArr.push(imageDiv);
        });

        if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
            setTimeout(() => roll(), 0);
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', init);
})();
```

Comment: the window object has a resize event that you can listen to.

Comment: Possible duplicate.. but it is not. Actually I want to remove the TimeOut and inline style from each div if the screen width is greater then 1200px.

Comment: Please read the FAQ [“This question may already have an answer here” - but it does not - or - What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252/215552) and the help center's [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [clearTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Save your settimeout to a variable so you can reference it in the clearTimeout() call

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

EDIT: Maybe setInterval is more appropriate here since you will want to constantly check the window size:

```
setInterval(function() { 
  if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
    // do the thing you want if its smaller than 1200
  } else {
    // do the other thing
  }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I don't want to clear the timeout only. But also remove the Scroll() inline style if the width is greater then 1200px.

Comment: I think I understand a little better now. Maybe you want something such as setInterval() instead of setTimeout? It can run every N seconds and you can have conditional logic inside of the interval to check the window.innerWidth

Comment: How do i make it work with my code?